# Broken MongoDB database after repair

Tags: mongodb

**Prerequisites**

I have MacBook Pro (*128 GB!* — it's maybe a reason of the problem, but I don't sure) with MacOS Yosemite (10.10.3). Also I have MongoDB 3.0 as system mongo. But I need Mongo 2.4 for one project. Next I'll talk about mongo 2.4, that I run so: `./mongod --dbpath=/data/db2.4/`. I got dump from production server, restored it locally some days ago and ran it. Everything was good, but…

**A problem description**

But yesterday I stopped mongo process by `Ctrl + C` in the iTerm. Now, I try to start it the same command like in *Prerequisites* section, but I see this log:

```
➜ ~/Downloads/mongodb-osx-x86_64-2.4.14/bin ./mongod --dbpath=/data/db2.4/ -vvvvv
Mon Jun 22 19:18:25.498 BackgroundJob starting: DataFileSync
Mon Jun 22 19:18:25.502 Matcher::matches() { abcd: 3.1, abcdef: "123456789" }
Mon Jun 22 19:18:25.502 Matcher::matches() { abcd: 3.1, abcdef: "123456789" }
Mon Jun 22 19:18:25.502 Matcher::matches() { abcd: 3.1, abcdef: "123456789" }
Mon Jun 22 19:18:25.502 Matcher::matches() { abcdef: "z23456789" }
Mon Jun 22 19:18:25.502 Matcher::matches() { abcd: 3.1, abcdef: "123456789" }
Mon Jun 22 19:18:25.502 Matcher::matches() { abcdef: "z23456789" }
Mon Jun 22 19:18:25.504 shardObjTest passed
Mon Jun 22 19:18:25.504 isInRangeTest passed
Mon Jun 22 19:18:25.504 shardKeyTest passed
Mon Jun 22 19:18:25.504 versionArrayTest passed
Mon Jun 22 19:18:25.505 [initandlisten] MongoDB starting : pid=1187 port=27017 dbpath=/data/db2.4/ 64-bit host=MacBook-Pro-lancedikson.local
Mon Jun 22 19:18:25.505 [initandlisten]
Mon Jun 22 19:18:25.505 [initandlisten] ** WARNING: soft rlimits too low. Number of files is 256, should be at least 1000
Mon Jun 22 19:18:25.505 [initandlisten] db version v2.4.14
Mon Jun 22 19:18:25.505 [initandlisten] git version: 05bebf9ab15511a71bfbded684bb226014c0a553
Mon Jun 22 19:18:25.505 [initandlisten] build info: Darwin bs-osx-106-x86-64-2.10gen.cc 10.8.0 Darwin Kernel Version 10.8.0: Tue Jun  7 16:32:41 PDT 2011; root:xnu-1504.15.3~1/RELEASE_X86_64 x86_64 BOOST_LIB_VERSION=1_49
Mon Jun 22 19:18:25.505 [initandlisten] allocator: system
Mon Jun 22 19:18:25.505 [initandlisten] options: { dbpath: "/data/db2.4/", vvvvv: true }
Mon Jun 22 19:18:25.507 [initandlisten] journal dir=/data/db2.4/journal
Mon Jun 22 19:18:25.507 [initandlisten] recover : no journal files present, no recovery needed
Mon Jun 22 19:18:25.519 [initandlisten] opening db:  local
Mon Jun 22 19:18:25.519 [initandlisten] mmf open /data/db2.4/local.ns
Mon Jun 22 19:18:25.519 [initandlisten] mmf finishOpening 0x105c06000 /data/db2.4/local.ns len:16777216
Mon Jun 22 19:18:25.611 [initandlisten] mmf open /data/db2.4/local.0
Mon Jun 22 19:18:25.611 [initandlisten] mmf finishOpening 0x107c06000 /data/db2.4/local.0 len:67108864
Mon Jun 22 19:18:25.611 [initandlisten] mmf close
Mon Jun 22 19:18:25.612 [initandlisten] enter repairDatabases (to check pdfile version #)
Mon Jun 22 19:18:25.612 [initandlisten]     admin
Mon Jun 22 19:18:25.612 [initandlisten] opening db:  admin
Mon Jun 22 19:18:25.612 [initandlisten] mmf open /data/db2.4/admin.ns
Mon Jun 22 19:18:25.612 [initandlisten] mmf finishOpening 0x10fc06000 /data/db2.4/admin.ns len:16777216
Mon Jun 22 19:18:25.612 [initandlisten] mmf open /data/db2.4/admin.0
Mon Jun 22 19:18:25.612 [initandlisten] mmf finishOpening 0x111c06000 /data/db2.4/admin.0 len:67108864
Mon Jun 22 19:18:25.613 [initandlisten] mmf open /data/db2.4/admin.1
Mon Jun 22 19:18:25.613 [initandlisten] mmf finishOpening 0x119c06000 /data/db2.4/admin.1 len:134217728
Mon Jun 22 19:18:25.613 [initandlisten] mmf close /data/db2.4/admin.1
Mon Jun 22 19:18:25.613 [initandlisten] _groupCommit
Mon Jun 22 19:18:25.613 [initandlisten] journal REMAPPRIVATEVIEW
Mon Jun 22 19:18:25.613 [initandlisten] journal REMAPPRIVATEVIEW done startedAt: 0 n:5 0ms
Mon Jun 22 19:18:25.613 [initandlisten] groupCommit end
Mon Jun 22 19:18:25.615 [initandlisten] mmf close /data/db2.4/admin.0
Mon Jun 22 19:18:25.615 [initandlisten] _groupCommit
Mon Jun 22 19:18:25.615 [initandlisten] journal REMAPPRIVATEVIEW
Mon Jun 22 19:18:25.615 [initandlisten] journal REMAPPRIVATEVIEW done startedAt: 0 n:1 0ms
Mon Jun 22 19:18:25.615 [initandlisten] groupCommit end
Mon Jun 22 19:18:25.615 [initandlisten] mmf close /data/db2.4/admin.ns
Mon Jun 22 19:18:25.615 [initandlisten] _groupCommit
Mon Jun 22 19:18:25.615 [initandlisten] journal REMAPPRIVATEVIEW
Mon Jun 22 19:18:25.615 [initandlisten] journal REMAPPRIVATEVIEW done startedAt: 1 n:1 0ms
Mon Jun 22 19:18:25.615 [initandlisten] groupCommit end
Mon Jun 22 19:18:25.615 [initandlisten]     local
Mon Jun 22 19:18:25.615 [initandlisten] ****
Mon Jun 22 19:18:25.615 [initandlisten] ****
Mon Jun 22 19:18:25.615 [initandlisten] need to upgrade database local with pdfile version 4.21, new version: 4.5
Mon Jun 22 19:18:25.615 [initandlisten]      Not upgrading, exiting
Mon Jun 22 19:18:25.615 [initandlisten]      run --upgrade to upgrade dbs, then start again
Mon Jun 22 19:18:25.615 [initandlisten] ****
Mon Jun 22 19:18:25.615 dbexit:
Mon Jun 22 19:18:25.615 [initandlisten] shutdown: going to close listening sockets...
Mon Jun 22 19:18:25.615 [initandlisten] shutdown: going to flush diaglog...
Mon Jun 22 19:18:25.615 [initandlisten] shutdown: going to close sockets...
Mon Jun 22 19:18:25.615 [initandlisten] shutdown: waiting for fs preallocator...
Mon Jun 22 19:18:25.615 [initandlisten] shutdown: lock for final commit...
Mon Jun 22 19:18:25.615 [initandlisten] shutdown: final commit...
Mon Jun 22 19:18:25.615 [initandlisten] _groupCommit
Mon Jun 22 19:18:25.615 [initandlisten] journal REMAPPRIVATEVIEW
Mon Jun 22 19:18:25.615 [initandlisten] journal REMAPPRIVATEVIEW done startedAt: 2 n:1 0ms
Mon Jun 22 19:18:25.615 [initandlisten] groupCommit end
Mon Jun 22 19:18:25.617 [initandlisten] shutdown: closing all files...
Mon Jun 22 19:18:25.617 [initandlisten] mmf close /data/db2.4/local.ns
Mon Jun 22 19:18:25.617 [initandlisten] _groupCommit
Mon Jun 22 19:18:25.617 [initandlisten] journal REMAPPRIVATEVIEW
Mon Jun 22 19:18:25.617 [initandlisten] journal REMAPPRIVATEVIEW done startedAt: 1 n:1 0ms
Mon Jun 22 19:18:25.617 [initandlisten] groupCommit end
Mon Jun 22 19:18:25.618 [initandlisten] mmf close /data/db2.4/local.0
Mon Jun 22 19:18:25.618 [initandlisten] _groupCommit
Mon Jun 22 19:18:25.618 [initandlisten] journal REMAPPRIVATEVIEW
Mon Jun 22 19:18:25.618 [initandlisten] journal REMAPPRIVATEVIEW done startedAt: 0 n:1 0ms
Mon Jun 22 19:18:25.618 [initandlisten] groupCommit end
Mon Jun 22 19:18:25.618 [initandlisten] closeAllFiles() finished
Mon Jun 22 19:18:25.618 [initandlisten] journalCleanup...
Mon Jun 22 19:18:25.618 [initandlisten] removeJournalFiles
Mon Jun 22 19:18:25.618 [initandlisten] removeJournalFiles end
Mon Jun 22 19:18:25.618 [initandlisten] shutdown: removing fs lock...
Mon Jun 22 19:18:25.618 [initandlisten] shutdown: groupCommitMutex
Mon Jun 22 19:18:25.618 dbexit: really exiting now
```

So, if I try add `--upgrade` key, I see this error:

```
~/Downloads/mongodb-osx-x86_64-2.4.14/bin ./mongod --dbpath=/data/db2.4/ -vvvvv --upgrade
Mon Jun 22 19:19:18.473 BackgroundJob starting: DataFileSync
Mon Jun 22 19:19:18.476 Matcher::matches() { abcd: 3.1, abcdef: "123456789" }
Mon Jun 22 19:19:18.476 Matcher::matches() { abcd: 3.1, abcdef: "123456789" }
Mon Jun 22 19:19:18.476 Matcher::matches() { abcd: 3.1, abcdef: "123456789" }
Mon Jun 22 19:19:18.476 Matcher::matches() { abcdef: "z23456789" }
Mon Jun 22 19:19:18.476 Matcher::matches() { abcd: 3.1, abcdef: "123456789" }
Mon Jun 22 19:19:18.476 Matcher::matches() { abcdef: "z23456789" }
Mon Jun 22 19:19:18.476 shardObjTest passed
Mon Jun 22 19:19:18.476 isInRangeTest passed
Mon Jun 22 19:19:18.476 shardKeyTest passed
Mon Jun 22 19:19:18.476 versionArrayTest passed
Mon Jun 22 19:19:18.476 [initandlisten] MongoDB starting : pid=1192 port=27017 dbpath=/data/db2.4/ 64-bit host=MacBook-Pro-lancedikson.local
Mon Jun 22 19:19:18.476 [initandlisten]
Mon Jun 22 19:19:18.476 [initandlisten] ** WARNING: soft rlimits too low. Number of files is 256, should be at least 1000
Mon Jun 22 19:19:18.476 [initandlisten] db version v2.4.14
Mon Jun 22 19:19:18.476 [initandlisten] git version: 05bebf9ab15511a71bfbded684bb226014c0a553
Mon Jun 22 19:19:18.476 [initandlisten] build info: Darwin bs-osx-106-x86-64-2.10gen.cc 10.8.0 Darwin Kernel Version 10.8.0: Tue Jun  7 16:32:41 PDT 2011; root:xnu-1504.15.3~1/RELEASE_X86_64 x86_64 BOOST_LIB_VERSION=1_49
Mon Jun 22 19:19:18.476 [initandlisten] allocator: system
Mon Jun 22 19:19:18.476 [initandlisten] options: { dbpath: "/data/db2.4/", upgrade: true, vvvvv: true }
Mon Jun 22 19:19:18.485 [initandlisten] journal dir=/data/db2.4/journal
Mon Jun 22 19:19:18.485 [initandlisten] recover : no journal files present, no recovery needed
Mon Jun 22 19:19:18.499 [initandlisten] opening db:  local
Mon Jun 22 19:19:18.499 [initandlisten] mmf open /data/db2.4/local.ns
Mon Jun 22 19:19:18.499 [initandlisten] mmf finishOpening 0x106000000 /data/db2.4/local.ns len:16777216
Mon Jun 22 19:19:18.506 [initandlisten] mmf open /data/db2.4/local.0
Mon Jun 22 19:19:18.506 [initandlisten] mmf finishOpening 0x108000000 /data/db2.4/local.0 len:67108864
Mon Jun 22 19:19:18.506 [initandlisten] mmf close
Mon Jun 22 19:19:18.506 [initandlisten] enter repairDatabases (to check pdfile version #)
Mon Jun 22 19:19:18.506 [initandlisten]     admin
Mon Jun 22 19:19:18.506 [initandlisten] opening db:  admin
Mon Jun 22 19:19:18.506 [initandlisten] mmf open /data/db2.4/admin.ns
Mon Jun 22 19:19:18.507 [initandlisten] mmf finishOpening 0x110000000 /data/db2.4/admin.ns len:16777216
Mon Jun 22 19:19:18.507 [initandlisten] mmf open /data/db2.4/admin.0
Mon Jun 22 19:19:18.507 [initandlisten] mmf finishOpening 0x112000000 /data/db2.4/admin.0 len:67108864
Mon Jun 22 19:19:18.518 [initandlisten] mmf open /data/db2.4/admin.1
Mon Jun 22 19:19:18.518 [initandlisten] mmf finishOpening 0x11a000000 /data/db2.4/admin.1 len:134217728
Mon Jun 22 19:19:18.518 [initandlisten] mmf close /data/db2.4/admin.1
Mon Jun 22 19:19:18.518 [initandlisten] _groupCommit
Mon Jun 22 19:19:18.518 [initandlisten] journal REMAPPRIVATEVIEW
Mon Jun 22 19:19:18.518 [initandlisten] journal REMAPPRIVATEVIEW done startedAt: 0 n:5 0ms
Mon Jun 22 19:19:18.518 [initandlisten] groupCommit end
Mon Jun 22 19:19:18.518 [initandlisten] mmf close /data/db2.4/admin.0
Mon Jun 22 19:19:18.518 [initandlisten] _groupCommit
Mon Jun 22 19:19:18.518 [initandlisten] journal REMAPPRIVATEVIEW
Mon Jun 22 19:19:18.518 [initandlisten] journal REMAPPRIVATEVIEW done startedAt: 0 n:1 0ms
Mon Jun 22 19:19:18.518 [initandlisten] groupCommit end
Mon Jun 22 19:19:18.518 [initandlisten] mmf close /data/db2.4/admin.ns
Mon Jun 22 19:19:18.518 [initandlisten] _groupCommit
Mon Jun 22 19:19:18.528 [initandlisten] journal REMAPPRIVATEVIEW
Mon Jun 22 19:19:18.528 [initandlisten] journal REMAPPRIVATEVIEW done startedAt: 1 n:1 0ms
Mon Jun 22 19:19:18.528 [initandlisten] groupCommit end
Mon Jun 22 19:19:18.528 [initandlisten]     local
Mon Jun 22 19:19:18.528 [initandlisten] ****
Mon Jun 22 19:19:18.528 [initandlisten] ****
Mon Jun 22 19:19:18.528 [initandlisten] need to upgrade database local with pdfile version 4.21, new version: 4.5
Mon Jun 22 19:19:18.528 [initandlisten]      starting upgrade
Mon Jun 22 19:19:18.528 [initandlisten]  local repairDatabase local
Mon Jun 22 19:19:18.528 [initandlisten] _groupCommit
Mon Jun 22 19:19:18.528 [initandlisten] journal REMAPPRIVATEVIEW
Mon Jun 22 19:19:18.528 [initandlisten] journal REMAPPRIVATEVIEW done startedAt: 2 n:1 0ms
Mon Jun 22 19:19:18.528 [initandlisten] groupCommit end
Mon Jun 22 19:19:18.530 [initandlisten] removeJournalFiles
Mon Jun 22 19:19:18.530 [initandlisten] removeJournalFiles end
Mon Jun 22 19:19:18.530 [initandlisten] checking size file /data/db2.4/local.ns
Mon Jun 22 19:19:18.530 [initandlisten] opening db: /data/db2.4/_tmp_repairDatabase_5 local
Mon Jun 22 19:19:18.531 [initandlisten] runQuery called local.system.namespaces {}
Mon Jun 22 19:19:18.531 [initandlisten] info PageFaultRetryableSection will not yield, already locked upon reaching
Mon Jun 22 19:19:18.531 [initandlisten] query local.system.namespaces ntoreturn:0 ntoskip:0 nscanned:2 keyUpdates:0  nreturned:2 reslen:150 0ms
Mon Jun 22 19:19:18.531 [initandlisten]      cloner got { name: "local.startup_log", options: { create: "startup_log", size: 10485760, capped: true } }
Mon Jun 22 19:19:18.531 [initandlisten]          not ignoring collection local.startup_log
Mon Jun 22 19:19:18.531 [initandlisten]      cloner got { name: "local.system.indexes" }
Mon Jun 22 19:19:18.531 [initandlisten]          not cloning because system collection
Mon Jun 22 19:19:18.531 [initandlisten]   really will clone: { name: "local.startup_log", options: { create: "startup_log", size: 10485760, capped: true } }
Mon Jun 22 19:19:18.531 [initandlisten] create collection local.startup_log { create: "startup_log", size: 10485760, capped: true }
Mon Jun 22 19:19:18.532 [initandlisten] allocating new ns file /data/db2.4/_tmp_repairDatabase_5/local.ns, filling with zeroes...
Mon Jun 22 19:19:18.585 [initandlisten] mmf create /data/db2.4/_tmp_repairDatabase_5/local.ns
Mon Jun 22 19:19:18.585 [initandlisten] mmf finishOpening 0x110000000 /data/db2.4/_tmp_repairDatabase_5/local.ns len:16777216
Mon Jun 22 19:19:18.586 [initandlisten] mmf create /data/db2.4/_tmp_repairDatabase_5/local.0
Mon Jun 22 19:19:18.586 [FileAllocator] allocating new datafile /data/db2.4/_tmp_repairDatabase_5/local.0, filling with zeroes...
Mon Jun 22 19:19:18.586 [FileAllocator] creating directory /data/db2.4/_tmp_repairDatabase_5/_tmp
Mon Jun 22 19:19:18.805 [FileAllocator] done allocating datafile /data/db2.4/_tmp_repairDatabase_5/local.0, size: 64MB,  took 0.218 secs
Mon Jun 22 19:19:18.805 [initandlisten] mmf finishOpening 0x112000000 /data/db2.4/_tmp_repairDatabase_5/local.0 len:67108864
Mon Jun 22 19:19:18.860 [initandlisten] allocExtent local.startup_log size 10485760 0
Mon Jun 22 19:19:18.860 [initandlisten] New namespace: local.startup_log
Mon Jun 22 19:19:18.862 [initandlisten] allocExtent local.system.namespaces size 5888 0
Mon Jun 22 19:19:18.862 [initandlisten] New namespace: local.system.namespaces
Mon Jun 22 19:19:18.862 [initandlisten]          cloning local.startup_log -> local.startup_log
Mon Jun 22 19:19:18.862 [initandlisten]         cloning collection local.startup_log to local.startup_log on localhost with filter {}
Mon Jun 22 19:19:18.862 [initandlisten] runQuery called local.startup_log {}
Mon Jun 22 19:19:18.862 [initandlisten] query local.startup_log ntoreturn:0 ntoskip:0 nscanned:1 keyUpdates:0  nreturned:1 reslen:856 0ms
Mon Jun 22 19:19:18.863 [initandlisten]         cloning collection local.system.indexes to local.system.indexes on localhost with filter { name: { $ne: "_id_" }, ns: { $nin: {} } }
Mon Jun 22 19:19:18.863 [initandlisten] runQuery called local.system.indexes { name: { $ne: "_id_" }, ns: { $nin: {} } }
Mon Jun 22 19:19:18.865 [initandlisten]  local.system.indexes Assertion failure dl.a() != -1 src/mongo/db/pdfile.h 646
0x10045236b 0x10042bfbc 0x100269200 0x1002692a0 0x1002c13a8 0x1002cec5a 0x1002d064b 0x1002d0858 0x10024335e 0x1002466a2 0x1001f18fb 0x1001e9a24 0x1001e9c2d 0x10006362a 0x100038e80 0x1001e95a1 0x10003a5bc 0x1000e8b76 0x1000eaaf4 0x1000eb5be
 0   mongod                              0x000000010045236b _ZN5mongo15printStackTraceERSo + 43
 1   mongod                              0x000000010042bfbc _ZN5mongo12verifyFailedEPKcS1_j + 284
 2   mongod                              0x0000000100269200 _ZN5mongo11DataFileMgr7findAllERKNS_10StringDataERKNS_7DiskLocE + 968
 3   mongod                              0x00000001002692a0 _ZN5mongo13findTableScanEPKcRKNS_7BSONObjERKNS_7DiskLocE + 128
 4   mongod                              0x00000001002c13a8 _ZNK5mongo9QueryPlan9newCursorERKNS_7DiskLocEb + 292
 5   mongod                              0x00000001002cec5a _ZN5mongo15CursorGenerator16singlePlanCursorEv + 214
 6   mongod                              0x00000001002d064b _ZN5mongo15CursorGenerator8generateEv + 97
 7   mongod                              0x00000001002d0858 _ZN5mongo25NamespaceDetailsTransient9getCursorERKNS_10StringDataERKNS_7BSONObjES6_RKNS_24QueryPlanSelectionPolicyERKN5boost10shared_ptrIKNS_11ParsedQueryEEEbPNS_16QueryPlanSummaryE + 56
 8   mongod                              0x000000010024335e _ZN5mongo23queryWithQueryOptimizerEiRKSsRKNS_7BSONObjERNS_5CurOpES4_S4_RKN5boost10shared_ptrINS_11ParsedQueryEEES4_RKNS_12ChunkVersionERNS7_10scoped_ptrINS_25PageFaultRetryableSectionEEERNSG_INS_19NoPageFaultsAllowedEEERNS_7MessageE + 446
 9   mongod                              0x00000001002466a2 _ZN5mongo8runQueryERNS_7MessageERNS_12QueryMessageERNS_5CurOpES1_ + 5346
 10  mongod                              0x00000001001f18fb _ZN5mongo16assembleResponseERNS_7MessageERNS_10DbResponseERKNS_11HostAndPortE + 1691
 11  mongod                              0x00000001001e9a24 _ZN5mongo14DBDirectClient4callERNS_7MessageES2_bPSs + 112
 12  mongod                              0x00000001001e9c2d _ZThn72_N5mongo14DBDirectClient4callERNS_7MessageES2_bPSs + 13
 13  mongod                              0x000000010006362a _ZN5mongo14DBClientCursor4initEv + 304
 14  mongod                              0x0000000100038e80 _ZN5mongo12DBClientBase5queryERKSsNS_5QueryEiiPKNS_7BSONObjEii + 180
 15  mongod                              0x00000001001e95a1 _ZN5mongo14DBDirectClient5queryERKSsNS_5QueryEiiPKNS_7BSONObjEii + 79
 16  mongod                              0x000000010003a5bc _ZN5mongo12DBClientBase5queryEN5boost8functionIFvRNS_27DBClientCursorBatchIteratorEEEERKSsNS_5QueryEPKNS_7BSONObjEi + 98
 17  mongod                              0x00000001000e8b76 _ZN5mongo6Cloner4copyEPKcS2_bbbbbbNS_5QueryE + 1228
 18  mongod                              0x00000001000eaaf4 _ZN5mongo6Cloner2goEPKcRKNS_12CloneOptionsERSt3setISsSt4lessISsESaISsEERSsPi + 5914
 19  mongod                              0x00000001000eb5be _ZN5mongo6Cloner2goEPKcRSsRKSsbbbbbbPi + 254
Mon Jun 22 19:19:18.933 [initandlisten] assertion 0 assertion src/mongo/db/pdfile.h:646 ns:local.system.indexes query:{ name: { $ne: "_id_" }, ns: { $nin: {} } }
Mon Jun 22 19:19:18.933 [initandlisten] query local.system.indexes query: { name: { $ne: "_id_" }, ns: { $nin: {} } } ntoreturn:0 keyUpdates:0 exception: assertion src/mongo/db/pdfile.h:646  reslen:71 69ms
Mon Jun 22 19:19:18.939 [initandlisten] nextSafe(): { $err: "assertion src/mongo/db/pdfile.h:646" }
Mon Jun 22 19:19:18.939 [initandlisten] User Assertion: 13106:nextSafe(): { $err: "assertion src/mongo/db/pdfile.h:646" }
Mon Jun 22 19:19:18.940 [initandlisten] exception in initAndListen: 13106 nextSafe(): { $err: "assertion src/mongo/db/pdfile.h:646" }, terminating
Mon Jun 22 19:19:18.940 dbexit:
Mon Jun 22 19:19:18.940 [initandlisten] shutdown: going to close listening sockets...
Mon Jun 22 19:19:18.940 [initandlisten] shutdown: going to flush diaglog...
Mon Jun 22 19:19:18.940 [initandlisten] shutdown: going to close sockets...
Mon Jun 22 19:19:18.940 [initandlisten] shutdown: waiting for fs preallocator...
Mon Jun 22 19:19:18.940 [initandlisten] shutdown: lock for final commit...
Mon Jun 22 19:19:18.940 [initandlisten] shutdown: final commit...
Mon Jun 22 19:19:18.940 [initandlisten] _groupCommit
Mon Jun 22 19:19:18.941 [journal] journal WRITETODATAFILES 1
Mon Jun 22 19:19:18.941 [journal] journal WRITETODATAFILES 2
Mon Jun 22 19:19:18.941 [journal] journal WRITETODATAFILES 0.173ms
Mon Jun 22 19:19:18.942 [initandlisten] groupCommit end
Mon Jun 22 19:19:18.949 [initandlisten] shutdown: closing all files...
Mon Jun 22 19:19:18.949 [initandlisten] mmf close /data/db2.4/local.ns
Mon Jun 22 19:19:18.950 [initandlisten] mmf close /data/db2.4/_tmp_repairDatabase_5/local.0
Mon Jun 22 19:19:18.950 [initandlisten] mmf close /data/db2.4/local.0
Mon Jun 22 19:19:18.950 [initandlisten] mmf close /data/db2.4/_tmp_repairDatabase_5/local.ns
Mon Jun 22 19:19:18.950 [initandlisten] closeAllFiles() finished
Mon Jun 22 19:19:18.950 [initandlisten] journalCleanup...
Mon Jun 22 19:19:18.950 [initandlisten] removeJournalFiles
Mon Jun 22 19:19:18.950 [initandlisten] removeJournalFiles end
Mon Jun 22 19:19:18.950 [initandlisten] shutdown: removing fs lock...
Mon Jun 22 19:19:18.950 [initandlisten] shutdown: groupCommitMutex
Mon Jun 22 19:19:18.950 dbexit: really exiting now
```

Do you have any ideas what's going on and how to fix it without drop all data?

Comment: Hi Dennis. I'm facing the same issue right now, did you manage to find a solution to your issue?

Comment: Hi @kramer65. I haven't any solution for you, besides reinstall DB from backup. But I got the reason of the bug: I had 2 different versions of MongoDB and I got the error when run one of them using `db` folder intended for another.